# Удалённое подключение к ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu

Купил удалённый сервер, установили на него ubuntu 18.04.
Дали доступ по ssh. 
Установил vncserver,подключился, графика ужас, неудобно, пытался в консоли поменять разрешение , не получилось.
Установил sudo apt-get install xrdp.
Удаленный рабочий стол смог подключится, но пропал меня пуск, боковая панель. Через ssh и vnc подключиться не могу.
Как исправить ситуацию?
Как подключится пр удаление, что бы нормальная графика и работоспособность была?

Comment: Любой графический интерфейс и удаленная работа через него на Ubuntu server это бред, вы постоянно будите плеваться, если вы не работаете через консоль, а хотите запускать оконные приложения, смените его на win server

Comment: Пусть так, как вернуть доступ в к ssh и vnc

Comment: Если у тебя отвалился ссх - значит ты что-то где-то накосячил. Что именно ты правил\удалял можешь сказать только ты. Учитывая, что ты туда не успела залить боевых конфигураций - просто перенакати всё с нуля и без график.

Comment: попробовал и ты оказался прав,консоль это круто и удобно.